# Boost Mem_fn and accessing member function of derived class

Tags: boost, bind, derived-class

I made a simple example to test boost bind's interaction with derived classes.

I created two subclasses with different getarea functions. I expected

```
g1 = boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(&Shape::getarea), Rec)
```

to print the area of Rectangle(10,20) but instead it printed '1'. I get the same when I instead write `Rectangle::getarea`. It prints the same even when I input other functions eg. member of Rectangle

```
double sum(double h,double w){return h+w;   }
```

and use

```
 g1 = boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(&Rectangle::sum), Rec,2,3)
```

**Question 1:** Why does it return '1'?Is that a default response for error?

My second problem is to do the same of printing g2 but now Rec is replaced by **iter, i.e. an object of some derived class type from a list of objects. Since getarea is a virtual fcn, once I get the above working it should be fine to just write:

```
g2= boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(& Shape::getarea , &(**iter));
```

**Question 2:** However, I was wondering if there is a way to return the classtype of **iter eg. classof(**iter) and then put it in g2 i.e.

```
g2= boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(& classof(**iter)::getarea , &(**iter));
```

When I ran g2 by writing Shape::getarea, I got '1' again for all iter.

```
   #include <memory>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
    using namespace std;

    class Shape {
        public:    
            Shape(double h, double w) :height(h), width(w) {};
            virtual double getarea() = 0;
            double height;
            double width; };

        class Rectangle: public Shape {
        public:   
            Rectangle(double h, double w): Shape(h,w) {};
            double getarea() override { return height*width; }    };

        class Triangle : public Shape {
        public:
                Triangle(double h, double w) :Shape(h,w) {};
                double getarea() { return height*width*0.5; }};

        int main() {
        //create objects
            Rectangle Rec(10, 20);
            Triangle Tri(2, 3);


        //create boost bind function
            boost::function<double(double, double)> g1;
            g1 = boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(&Shape::getarea), Rec);
    //print area and g
            cout << Rec.getarea()<<" should be equal to " << g1<< '\n';


    //create list
            vector<shared_ptr<Shape>> Plist;
            Plist.push_back(make_shared<Rectangle>(Rec));
            Plist.push_back(make_shared<Triangle>(Tri));


        //print each element from the vector list 

        for (auto iter = Plist.begin(); iter != Plist.end(); iter ++ ) {

                boost::function<double(double, double)> g2;

                g2= boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(& ....  , &(**iter));

        //where in dots we need Classtype_of_**iter::getarea 

            cout << (**iter).getarea()<<"should be equal to " << g2<< '\n';

        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You... forget to invoke the functions...

```
for (auto iter = Plist.begin(); iter != Plist.end(); iter++) {
    boost::function<double()> g2;
    g2 = boost::bind(&Shape::getarea, iter->get());
    cout << (*iter)->getarea() << " should be equal to " << g2() << '\n';
}
```

What you saw what the implicit conversion to bool (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/function.html#idm45507164686720-bb)

Note also I fixed the signature of `g1` and `g2`: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa14f0fcbedca93c)**.

Some further improvements (remove the need for the g2 in the loop?):

```
auto getarea = boost::mem_fn(&Shape::getarea);
for (auto iter = Plist.begin(); iter != Plist.end(); iter++) {
    cout << (*iter)->getarea() << " should be equal to " << getarea(**iter) << '\n';
}
```

Or, indeed in c++11:

```
for (auto& s : Plist)
    cout << s->getarea() << " should be equal to " << getarea(*s) << '\n';
```

By this time, you'd wonder why you have this accessor when you can just use the member.